# Invalid file name in report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

My web application is hosted with Arvixe. I also uploaded the *aspnet_client* folder. This worked fine but after few days it showed an error:

> invalid file name

The error occurs when calling `rd.Load(path)`. This works on my local machine and on iis7. I've tried to give full permission on *c:\windows\Temp folder*;
used `rd.Close();`, `rd.Dispose();`, and `GC.Collect();` in the code behind.
I even checked *increase Print Limit for Crystal Reports* in the windows registry.

How can I fix this error?

```
CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: Load report failed. ---> 
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Invalid file name. at 
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options) at
 CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options) at 
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened() at
 CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob) at
 CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename) at STAREX.ReportViewer.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\abc\ReportViewer.aspx.cs:line 49
```

The page load for ReportViewer.aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    if ((DataTable)Session["datatable"] != null)
    {
      dt = (DataTable)Session["datatable"];
    }
    else
    {
      dt=null;
    }
    string path = Session["path"].ToString();

    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
      Response.Write("Unable to Locate");
    }
    else
    {
      rd = new ReportDocument();
      rd.Load(path);
      rd.SetDataSource(dt);
      CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  }
}
```

The report is called from the Data_Entry.aspx page:

```
protected void lnkPrintInvoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    LinkButton lnkbtn = sender as LinkButton;
    GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    string code = (gridDataEntryDetail.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value).ToString();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = bll.td_Bll("Select * from [View_Invoice] where Invoice_No ='" + code + "' ");

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
      Session["Invoice"] = "Invoice";
      dt.TableName = "View_Invoice";
      Session["datatable"] = dt;
      Session["path"] = Server.MapPath("~/Report/Crybilldom.rpt");
      Response.Redirect("~/ReportViewer.aspx");
    }
  }

  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    ExceptioError.Attributes.Remove("style");
    lblExcption.Visible = true;
    lblExcption.Text = "Exception Error !\t\t" + ex.Message;
  }
}
```

Comment: What server are you on?  I'm on orchid.arvixe.com and have basically the same issue starting about a week ago.  My reports worked fine for months before that, and nothing has changed.

Comment: I'm on arivixe.com. I have googled more and more sites but still not get any solution. I think it's a server error.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, just change your hosting server which supports crystal.
AVEN.arvixe.com supports crystal but sometime it is not support don't know why,so i do not recommend to arvixe if you have to use crystal report.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the answer was to contact Arvixe support.  Seems it was a permissions issue.  Their response:

> We have been making some system architectural changes on our shared server farm, so that we can provide a better service to our customers, we are working to get the configuration uniform across the platform. One of the things affected during this change is permissions to certain drives. We are actively working on a solution that gives us the security we are looking for while allowing Crystal reports users access to run the reports.
>
> I have made some edits to the system if you could test it and let us know if this fixes your issue.